# How to stop automatic scroll up in recycler view when increment button is clicked in recycler view item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I click the increment/decrement quantity button in recycler view, the recycler view is getting scrolled up automatically. How do I avoid scrolling up automatically??
Below is my code. Please help me.

This is the code in my main activity for recycler view adapter setup

```
private void loadCartItems() {
        //init list
        //get orders

        shopNameTv.setText(shopname);

        cartList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart")

                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //clear list before adding item
                        cartList.clear();

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            CartModel cartModel = ds.getValue(CartModel.class);
                            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.getValue();

                            Object price = map.get("Item_Price");
                            int cost = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(price));

                            allTotalPrice +=  cost ;
                            sTotalTv.setText("₹" +  allTotalPrice);
                            allTotalPriceTv.setText("₹" + (allTotalPrice + Integer.parseInt(deliveryFee.replace("₹", ""))));
                            cartList.add(cartModel);

                        }

                        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                        cartItemsRv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

                        cartItemsRv.setItemAnimator(null);
                        //setup adapter
                        cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(CartActivity.this, cartList);
                        //set adapter
                        cartItemsRv.scrollToPosition(cartList.size());

                      

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

        //allTotalPrice = allTotalPrice + Integer.parseInt(price);
        dFeeTv.setText("₹" + deliveryFee);
        sTotalTv.setText("₹" +  allTotalPrice);
        allTotalPriceTv.setText("₹" + (allTotalPrice + Integer.parseInt(deliveryFee.replace("₹", ""))));


    }
```

This is my adapter code

```
if (Integer.parseInt(stk) == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Product Stock Limit reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {

        holder.incrementBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int number = 0;
                number = Integer.parseInt(holder.itemQuantityTv.getText().toString().trim());
                number++;

                //((CartActivity)context).reload();

                holder.itemQuantityTv.setText(""+number);
                int pe = number * Integer.parseInt(holder.itemPriceEachTv.getText().toString().trim());
                holder.itemPriceTv.setText(""+pe);

                double tx = Double.parseDouble((((CartActivity)context).allTotalPriceTv.getText().toString().trim().replace("₹","")));
                double totalPrice = tx + Double.parseDouble(cartModel.getItem_Price().replace("₹",""));
                double deliveryFee = Double.parseDouble((((CartActivity)context).deliveryFee.replace("₹","")));
                double sTotalPrice = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.0f", totalPrice));
                ((CartActivity)context).allTotalPrice = 0;
                ((CartActivity)context).sTotalTv.setText("₹"+String.format("%.0f", sTotalPrice));
                ((CartActivity)context).allTotalPriceTv.setText("₹"+String.format("%.0f", Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.0f", sTotalPrice))));


                HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("Item_Price", "" + pe);
                hashMap.put("Item_Quantity", "" + number);
                hashMap.put("Available_Stock", "" + availableStock);

                //update db
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                ref.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(cartModel.getItem_PID()).updateChildren(hashMap)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                //db updated

                              //  Toast.makeText(context, "Cart updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                //failed updating db
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Cart not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                //To update stock value in cart
                int stk_number = 0;
                stk_number = Integer.parseInt(holder.stock.getText().toString().trim());

                if (stk_number >0 ){
                    stk_number--;

                    holder.stock.setText(""+stk_number);

                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap1.put("Stock_left", "" + stk_number);

                    //update db
                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                    reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").child(cartModel.getItem_PID()).updateChildren(hashMap1)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    //db updated
                                 //   Toast.makeText(context, "Cart updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    //failed updating db
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Cart not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
                else {
                    stk_number = 0;
                }

            }
        });
        }
```

Whenever I click increment/decrement button in recycler view item, the recycler view is scrolled up automatically. If I need to increment again, I need to scroll down again every time. So, how to stop this auto-scroll up and make it stay in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `ValueEventListener` after successful loading and populating the `Adapter`. Otherwise, you get an update event after updating the value. This creates a new `Adapter` which is scrolled to the top.

You can use `.get()` if you want to read the DB only once:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once

In your case:

```
reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Cart").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
     ...
}
```

Comment: what can we use instead of ValueEventListener as an alternative ? --@Daniel

Comment: I think it is the right way to load the data from the db, but if you create a new `Adapter` and scroll at the end on every data base update your behaviour is expected. It looks for me you use the function only for initial loading, so you have to remove the listener when finishing initial loading.

Comment: How can I remove the listener ater finishing the initial load .?..

Comment: After checking the documentation I learned that in your case you could use `.get()` to just load the data once: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_get. --> I updated my answer.

Comment: Im trying this and will let u know the status